# Upload input on Internet Explorer 8 and Chrome has differences to implement

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, file-io

I'm using a very simple method to get a file and upload it using different browser.
Well, my issue is:
I have a simple file upload defined in my html as:

`<input type='file' id='fileToUpload' />`

And trying to get it with:

```
$('input#fileToUpload')[0].files[0];
```

or using:

`$('#fileToUpload').prop('files')[0];`

Those 2 options works well on all the browsers (and on the newest IE versions), but not on IExplorer.

There I got `null` every time that I tried to get the files.

How I can solve it?

Comment: I don't think IE8 supports that at all.

Comment: which version of jquery you use?

Comment: @Dekel jQuery v1.12.4

Comment: Can you provide a working example? a jsfiddle or snippet... what you expect to get here?